# Sending request to Dialogflow from server

Tags: webhooks, chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I have created a Dialogflow messenger bot by integrating it to Facebook. Now FB send a request to Dialogflow and Dialogflow send the response to FB.

```
FB --> Dialogflow
Dialogflow --> FB
```

I want to put my server in the middle process. So that FB request will come to my server and my server will send a request to Dialogflow.

```
FB --> My Server --> Dialogflow
Dialogflow --> My Server --> FB
```

Is this possible? If so is there any PHP libraries or tutorials I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future Readers this is the way I found to fulfill my requirement.

In here I want my server to act as the middleman and identify the intent.

```
FB --> My Server --> Dialogflow
Dialogflow --> My Server --> FB
```

In Dialogflow v2 you can use the DitectIntent to identify the Intent. 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent

The SDKs available for different programming languages are available here. https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis

Answer (score 2):

Dialogflow supports sending data to servers.

You'll need to go to the Fulfillment tab to your project and enable Webhook

[image]

There you can set up the URL for where it should send the data including headers and authentication between your server and Dialogflow

---

Once you connect Dialogflow to Facebook all conversations will be routed through Dialogflow so the webhook is your best chance to do the communication. After that you just return a response to Dialogflow and it will send it for you

You can read more about Fulfillment from the documentation from Dialogflow: https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment

Comment: Fulfillment sends data to server as a post request and and get a response. I want to send a post request to Dialogflow and get a response.

Comment: Check this out: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query Is this what you need?

Comment: I want to act like the middle man here. So I want to send the text and see what actions and what response is available for the text. I think the agent/query does this. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Just remember, all conversations the user will have will be routed through Dialogflow first

Comment: Can you explain it to me. I didn't get it. Can't I use it as I said above? 
"I want to send the text and see what actions and what response is available for the text."

Comment: With Dialogflow Integrations your interactions are `FB -> Dialogflow -> FB` In case of a webhook it will be ` FB -> Dialogflow -> Webhook -> Dialogflow -> FB` You can probably ditch the integration and when you get the message send a post request to the /query endpoint

Comment: [http://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query](http://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) was only available for v1. Now its not available.

Comment: I think now it's available on here [https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) 
thanks for the help mate.